# Check Ion cache before loading

Tags: android, networking, android-ion

I want to check if an image is in the cache of Ion before calling to load so I don't set the in animation.

```
Ion.with(view).animateIn(animation).load(url)
```

alternatively is there another way to **only** do the animation when the image is loaded from a remote location?